# Laravel 8 fetching coordinates data and display in Google Maps in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, laravel, google-maps

I have coordinates stored in my database, and I want to fetch those coordinates to display on Google Maps, where the user will click on the link which says like **"view on map"** in the column table. However, the link will redirect to that map based on stored coordinates from the database, and I don't know how to fetch those coordinates from the database with JavaScript.

```
var map;
var myLatLng;

function initMap() {
  
  var loc = { lat: -74.17972, lng:34.56445312 };
 
  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: loc,
  });
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: loc,
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way to make client js talks to you db , will be through an API Call by Ajax.

You can create an Api route and controller function to handle query the coords
from the DB and test it out